# Angular js api url call not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: "/api/v1/coupons-dunia/coupons-by-website?websiteId=1"}).success(function(data) {
           $scope.onlinedata = data.coupons;
           $scope.website = data.websites;
        });
```

When I pass `www.mydomain.com/cccc/xxxx/` its working fine,But when i try to pass `/api/v1/coupons-dunia/coupons-by-website?websiteId=1` its show error, `"SyntaxError: illegal character"`

I am using AngularJS v1.2.21 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: "/api/v1/coupons-dunia/coupons-by-website", params: {websiteId:1})
```